# ATmega328p keeps restarting

Tags: atmel, arduino-uno

When I was programming an arduino uno with atmel studio via usb cable, everything worked fine. Now I am trying to upload a code via usbasp programmer, it works, whereas arduino keeps restarting and L labelled pin flashes even when I have not activated it by code. After a bit searching I've found that,I should unprogram watchdog timer by adding this command:

**C:\Users\Eldar>avrdude -c usbasp -p m328 -P COM5 -b 19200 -U lfuse:w:0xEF:m -U hfuse:w:0xD9:m**
output of that:

```
 avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update. avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept
    instructions Reading |
    ################################################## | 100% 0.03s avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f avrdude: reading input file
    "0xEF" avrdude: writing lfuse (1 bytes): Writing |
    ################################################## | 100% 0.01s avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse written avrdude: verifying lfuse memory
    against 0xEF: avrdude: load data lfuse data from input file 0xEF:
    avrdude: input file 0xEF contains 1 bytes avrdude: reading on-chip
    lfuse data: Reading |
    ################################################## | 100% 0.01s avrdude: verifying ... avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse verified avrdude:
    reading input file "0xD9" avrdude: writing hfuse (1 bytes): Writing
    | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s
    avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse written avrdude: verifying hfuse memory
    against 0xD9: avrdude: load data hfuse data from input file 0xD9:
    avrdude: input file 0xD9 contains 1 bytes avrdude: reading on-chip
    hfuse data: Reading |
    ################################################## | 100% 0.02s avrdude: verifying ... avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse verified avrdude:
    safemode: Fuses OK avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I changed  0xD9 to 0xC9 but it`s still the same.Moreover,when i try to program arduino with usb cable again,avrdude gives this error:

```
avrdude.exe: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude.exe done.  Thank you.
```

This is my code that I try to upload just for testing

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
int main(void)
{
    DDRD |= 0B11111111;
    DDRB |= 0B11111111;
    while(1)
    {
    PORTD |= 0B00110000;
    PORTB |= 0B00110000;
    _delay_ms(1000);
     PORTD ^= 0B00000000; 
     PORTB ^= 0B00000000;
    }
}
```

I`ve also tried unprogram watchdog timer inside the program itself,it`s still the same.There are attempts below.
Attempt1

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
    #include <avr/io.h>
    #include <util/delay.h>
    #include <avr/wdt.h>
     int main(void)
    {
    MCUSR = 0;
    wdt_disable( );
     while(1)
     {
        //nothing 
     }
     }
```

Attempt2

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>
 int main(void)
{


    wdt_reset();
     MCUSR=0;
     WDTCSR|=_BV(WDCE) | _BV(WDE);
     WDTCSR=0;
     while(1)
     {
        //nothing 
     }
     }
```

Also,why it does not work when i configure the chip with avrdude directly via command line either?

Comment: Professional programs always have the watchdog enabled. The correct fix is to write to the relevant watchdog refresh register once from the main `while(1)` loop. For debug build, you can disable the watchdog. But it's good to have even then, if you can set it to freeze upon single step debugging, because it will expose timing problems in your program.

Comment: (But then again, Ardunio was never meant to be used for non-hobbyist purposes)

Comment: Could you suggest relevant code for watchdog refresh register once from the main while(1) loop,because I`ve tried these(in the below comment),but it`s still the same